# Microsoft Word: Toggling visibility of form instructions

Tags: microsoft-word

Context: OS X   Word 2011

A MS-Word form has plenty of useful instructions (coded in red font).   How would one "tag" or "label" these instructions so that one could dismiss (hide) them when printing and summon them when in need of guidance \ instruction.  Bonus if this could be done by toggling a button added to the menu.

Comment: This is not a default behavior of Microsoft Word, as Word is a page-layout application, not a form-filling application. Form filling is a secondary feature that only exists within the context of the primary feature of Word: putting text and other content onto real-sized pages.

Answer (score 2):

Set up the instructions as their own style (colour, font, italics etc.) and include the property "hidden".

All you need after this is a button/command to show/hide 'hidden' text. Under default behaviour, the `reverse P` button will show all formatting and layout items - but this can be tailored in `Options`. I have not had a in-depth look to see if this display option can be tailored for individual documents or whether it can only be tailored for the Application as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic Code to be inserted in module of word document:

```
Sub toggleHidenText()
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = _
 Not ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText
End Sub
```

Bind Macro to keyboard shortcut CTL-SHFT-J:

```
Menu item = Tools
Categories=macros
select toggleHidenText
type in keyboard shortcut CTL-SHFT-J and then assign
OK
```